# React useState set state causes <canvas> append to html

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, use-state

React `useState`, while I am setting state, some strange `<canvas>` appends to main `<html>`!

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import './style.scss';

export default () => {
    const [auth, setAuth] = useState(false);
    const handleAuth = () => setAuth(true);

    return (
        <header>
            <button onClick={handleAuth}>handle auth</button>
        </header>
    );
};
```

When button clicked, the strange `<canvas>` appends to `<html>` beginning.

```
<html lang="en">
<canvas style="inset: 0px; pointer-events: none; position: fixed; z-index: 1000000000;" width="1920" height="514"></canvas>
<head>
...
```

Comment: check your site in incognito mode. This might happen for any browser extensions.

Comment: Yes, thanks, you are right.

Comment: I hope my answer counts. Best of luck

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to check your site in incognito mode.

This might happen for any browser extensions.

Answer (score 8):

This canvas gets injected from the "React Developer Tools" extension.
It is used to highlight updates when a component renders.